# How to use AWS S3 raster file in Mapbox gl js?

Tags: html, amazon-s3, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Mapping a Cloud Optimized Geotiff raster layer in Mapbox GL JS

I think I use a raster source, the source data need to be tiled. the URL would be like `.../{z}/{x}/{y}.tif`.

But I don't know how to make above URL. how to make url??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. If you're asking "how do I turn this GeoTIFF into a tiled raster source", two options are:

1. Upload it to Mapbox. (In theory this works, although it has not always been successful for me.)
2. Use GDAL to convert it to `mbtiles`, then host the `.mbtiles` file somewhere (either on Mapbox, CloudTiler, or your own hosting.)

In the latter case, that would look like:

`gdal_translate myfile.tif mytiles.mbtiles`

Comment: Is it possible without using mbtile and not uploading to mapbox?

Comment: I just want to overlay my cog file on basemap as a raster tile source not image.

Comment: You're asking "can I use a raster tile source without having any raster tiles?" This doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox SDK wants to fetch tiles by Z/X/Y. However, you can probably register a NSURLProtocol subclass where you can take the Z/X/Y URL and create the proper COG request, transform the image and return the correct content.

I have used this to register mbtiles:// as a URL scheme and my NSURLProtocol subclass transform the Z/X/Y URL to a SQLite select statement.

You can read more on this subject over at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/12026